# Объединение массивов

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дано 2 больших статических массива: `A` типа `int []` и `B` типа `const int []`.

Как за линейное время дописать в `A` все те элементы `B`, которых нет в `A`?

Comment: Задача бессмысленна, так как неограниченное нельзя пересчитать за ограниченное время.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow в смысле могут быть большими (чтобы видеть различия в скорости алгоритмов)

Comment: За линейное время задание не выполнить.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Почему так?

Comment: Потому что линейное время - это простое копирование из одного массива в другой, когда для выполнения операции вам не надо знать о других элементах массивов. Все остальное имеет нелинейное время.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Если заменить типы массивов на `char []` и `const char []` соответственно, то можно за линейное время

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Т.е. нужно как-то по-другому доказать это

Comment: Я убежден, что в общем случае это сделать нельзя.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow В общем случае может и нельзя, но, создав дополнительный массив на 256 элементов, за 2 цикла (сложность 2n равносильна n) можно с `char`, а это противоречит вашему доказательству

Comment: Я не приводил доказательств. Я сказал, что в общем случае это сделать нельзя. Вы же сейчас рассматривается частный пример, когда множество значений ограничено. Но даже в вашем примере невозможно дописать элементы в том порядке, как они расположены в массиве B. То есть, фактически, это уже не будет операцией "дописывания"., так как порядок элементов относительно друг другу вам не удастся сохранить.

Answer (score 1):

Задача имеет тривиальное решение в виде урезанного варианта counting sort, с использованием примерно `2^sizeof(int)` дополнительной памяти.

```
vector<bool> has_number(max(A) + 1);
for (int x : A) has_number[x] = true;
for (int x : B) if (!has_number[x]) append(x);
```

Если нам не важен порядок элементов, и в A нет повторяющихся элементов - то можно сделать следующее:

- дописываем весь B в конец A,
- сортируем A за O(n) с помощью radix sort,
- удаляем дубликаты.

Все операции выполняются за O(n), соответственно общее время будет линейным.